# Is it possible to make this matrix operation any faster?

Tags: python, performance, tensor, numba

I would like to compute
[image]

for fixed iN and i0 with G being an nxn array of complex numbers and F being in principle an (N+1)x(N+1)xnxn array of complex numbers. However, F has a symmetry such that F(k,j)=F(k-j+1,1) if j>=1, so F can be stored in an array of shape (N+1)x2xnxn. Typical values would for example be N=20 and n=4.

Currently, I use Python with jit and my corresponding function looks like:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def calc():
    out = np.complex128(0)
    i = np.empty(N+1,np.int32) # index array
    i[0] = i0
    i[N] = iN
    for j in range(n**(N-1)): # one execution of the inner of this loops corresponds to one term in the large sum
        for k in range(1,N): # this loops calculates the index array
            i[k] = j % n
            j = j // n

        F_temp = np.complex128(1)
        for kpr in range(N+1):
            F_temp = F_temp * F[kpr,0,i[kpr],i[0]]
            for kprpr in range(1,kpr+1):
                F_temp = F_temp * F[kpr-kprpr+1,1,i[kpr],i[kprpr]]

        G_temp = np.complex128(1)
        for k in range(N):
            G_temp = G_temp * G[i[k+1],i[k]]

        out += G_temp * F_temp
    return out
```

I feel like this implementation is very far from optimal (by maybe an order of magnitude). If I use np.complex64 instead of np.complex128 for example, I see no speedup at all (which should not be the case for an efficient implementation, right?).
So, here is the question: Is there any chance I could reach a 10X speedup on this (or at least something in that ballpark)? Like implementing this function in another language and calling it from python (would that even neccessarily be faster than numba)?